# Removing event listeners on a currently emitting event

Tags: node.js, events, stream

I have the following sample app, written in Node.js:

```
'use strict';

var events = require('events'),
    util = require('util');

var EventEmitter = events.EventEmitter;

var Foo = function () {};

util.inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);

var foo = new Foo();

foo.once('x', function () {
  foo.removeAllListeners();
  console.log('Google!');
});

foo.once('x', function () {
  foo.removeAllListeners();
  console.log('Yahoo!');
});

foo.emit('x');
```

It prints:

```
Google!
Yahoo!
```

Now my question is: Apparently the `removeAllListeners` does not affect the event listeners that are currently bound to the event. Is this by random, or is this by intent? (I checked this out using 0.10.32 as well as 0.11.13)

The background of my question is: If I bind two event handlers to a stream's `end` event, and one of them calls `removeAllListeners`, does Node.js guarantee that both will always be run, or is this just by good luck?

Comment: Do you realize that you do not have to inherit from an `EventEmitter`, just to use one?  Your code above would work just fine with `var foo = new EventEmitter();`.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's just sample code that was copy/pasted and stripped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at the implementation of the `.emit()` method, it looks like once it starts processing an event and calling listeners, that event will not be affected by any code that calls `removeAllListeners()` so in your example both listeners will be called.

The code for `.emit()` makes a copy of the array of listeners before executing any of them so that once it starts executing one, it will execute all of them, even if they are removed during execution.  Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
  } else if (util.isObject(handler)) {
    len = arguments.length;
    args = new Array(len - 1);
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
      args[i - 1] = arguments[i];

    listeners = handler.slice();
    len = listeners.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
      listeners[i].apply(this, args);
  }
```

From the EventEmitter implementation here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/857975d5e7e0d7bf38577db0478d9e5ede79922e/lib/events.js#L120

In this piece of code, `handler` will be an array of listener functions.  The line

```
listeners = handler.slice()
```

makes a copy of the listeners array before any listeners are executed.  This is to be expected because iteration of that array can be messed up (duplicates or skips) if code is freely allowed to modify the array being iterated while it is being iterated.  So, it freezes the set of listeners to be called before calling any of them.

Comment: my two cents: 1. though this behaviour is intended, it's not documented, so it's not guaranteed. 2. `removeAllListeners` shouldn't be used at all, because you risk to remove internal listeners.

Comment: @vkurchatkin - true, it is not documented.  If you use node.js much, you will find that most behavior details like this are not well documented (the code is good, the documentation is not).  You have to look at the code to see what it does.  In this particular case, it is to be expected that the set of listeners that will fire is set before the first listener is fired because that is the most deterministic behavior and the simplest and most reliable way to implement.  FYI, even removing only the second event listener while the first is executing will not prevent the second from being called.

Comment: @vkurchatkin - so, because the documentation is so light, you simply cannot rely only on documented behavior.  There just isn't enough documented to do that.  To your point though, I wouldn't write the code the way the OP has.  If they want control over which piece of which event listener executes, then all the code for that even should probably be in one event listener where their own code can branch as appropriate.  That would make this whole issue moot.

Comment: @jfriend00 sad, but true. Still you can't say that it's "guaranteed". Anyway, opening a PR to add this to docs seems easy.

Comment: @jfriend00 reading tests is probably more reliable: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-event-emitter-modify-in-emit.js

Comment: @vkurchatkin - It would be good to add that to the doc.  Since the developer controls the exact version of node that they run with, you know (or can know) the exact node code you are running against and can guarantee exactly what it will do by examining the code.  So, in some cases (where you aren't going to blindly upgrade your version of node without paying attention to changes), you can know exactly what you're going to get.  Always better to write code that isn't dependent upon undocumented implementation details if possible, but often not possible with node.

Comment: @vkurchatkin - that test just tests to make sure that removing the handler that is being called from within the handler itself doesn't keep other handlers from being called.  It doesn't actually test what the OP was asking about which is about removing other event handlers that haven't yet been called on this event.